# How To Fix A Recursive Method That Selects Elements from A List

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

The problem is I want to select beams that are coincident on each other with just a click. I have a code that checks if they are connected. Find the code below

```
  public bool ElementsConnect(Element firstelement, Element secondelement)
    {
       ElementGeometry geo= new ElementGeometry();
       bool istrue ;
       List<XYZ> firstendpoints = GetEndPoints(firstelement);
       List<XYZ> secondendpoints = GetEndPoints(secondelement); 
       return istrue = firstendpoints.Any(firspoint => secondendpoints.Any
       (secondpoint => secondpoint.X == firspoint.X && secondpoint.Y==firspoint.Y
       && secondpoint.Z==firspoint.Z));
    }
```

Now I need the second method to recursively cycle through the list to find others that are joined till there is none. This is where I am failing to find a solution. Help will be greatly appreciated. Let me add that this code never gets out of the loop.

```
 public List<Element> GetConnectedBeams(Element element, List<Element> elements)
    {
       List<Element> beams = new List<Element>();
       for(int i=0; i < elements.Count();  i++)
       {
          if(ElementsConnect( element,elements[i]))
             beams.Add(elements[i]);
       }    
       List<Element> eles = null;
       foreach (var beam in beams) 
       {
          Element ele= elements.Find(x=> beams.Contains(x));
          eles = elements.Where(x=> x!= ele).ToList();
          beams= GetConnectedBeams(beam,eles) ;                                 
       }                
       return beams;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) has repeatedly discussed how to retrieve connected elements. Maybe the article on [Filtering for Touching Beams Using Solid Intersection](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/09/filter-for-touching-beams-using-solid-intersection.html) meets your needs pretty well.

Comment: The suggested solution is not consistent. Since I want to select beams that are coincident I modified the last bit of your code as seen below


`List<ElementId> groupvisited = visited.Where(X=> geo.IsParallel(doc.GetElement(X),element)).GroupBy(x=> geo.GetYintersect(doc.GetElement(x))).Where(x=> x.Key == geo.GetYintersect(element)).SelectMany(gro=> gro).ToList();`


`uidoc.Selection.SetElementIds(groupvisited);TaskDialog.Show("Succeeded", Result.Succeeded.ToString());`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy I was able to resolve the issue based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code

```
   for(int i=0; i < elements.Count();  i++)
```

you are already iterating over all elements because you wrote you only want to check connections till there is no one left.

Or am I understanding something wrong?

Edit:

How about that?

```
 while (beams.Any())
 {
    foreach (var beam in beams) 
    {
       Element ele= elements.Find(x=> beams.Contains(x));
       eles = elements.Where(x=> x!= ele).ToList();
       beams= GetConnectedBeams(beam,eles) ;                                 
    }  
 }
```

Comment: I need to cycle through the list to find the elements that connects to the queried element. based on the resulting list, find other elements that connect to the results  in that order till there is none .